# UILocalizedIndexedCollation with array of strings

Tags: ios, swift, uilocalizedcollation

`uniqueOrganizationsArray` is of `[String]` type.

```
private let collation = UILocalizedIndexedCollation.currentCollation() as UILocalizedIndexedCollation
private var sections: [[String]] = []
let selector: Selector = ""

            sections = [[String]](count: collation.sectionTitles.count, repeatedValue: [])

            for object in uniqueOrganizationsArray {
                let sectionNumber = collation.sectionForObject(object, collationStringSelector: selector)
                sections[sectionNumber].append(object as String)
            }
```

What selector should I use on `String` object?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `self` or `description` for String type. I prefer `self` because it can be used with any types. When using self, you would compare objects itself

```
let selector: Selector = "self"
let selector: Selector = "description"
```